# Recommended method (speed, clarity) for adding numbers given as command line arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, command-line

The problem is to get the command line arguments in terminal when the Node JS program is run, convert the arguments from string to number and then print the sum of the numbers entered as arguments.

Which method is better and in what way?

Method 1:

```
var calcArray = [];
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
    if(index > 1) {
        calcArray.push(parseInt(val));
    }
});
var answer = calcArray.reduce( (a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(answer);
```

Method 2:

```
var result = 0; 
for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
    result += Number(process.argv[i])
}

console.log(result)
```

- Method 1 : CPU Time: 0.08 sec(s), Memory: 29560 kilobyte(s)
- Method 2 : CPU Time: 0.09 sec(s), Memory: 29216 kilobyte(s)

I'm new to Node in general.